# Flutter Riverpod FutureProvider Not Working

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Hi I'm new to Flutter Riverpod. I'm trying to render a route page based on my `AuthState`, but when the state is updated, the `FutureProvider` does not call a method in the `authNotifier` provider.

Here is my Code.

```dart
final initializationProvider = FutureProvider<AuthState>((ref) async {
  final authNotifier = ref.read(authNotifierProvider.notifier);
  final state = await authNotifier.checkAndUpdateAuthStatus();
  return state;
});

class AppWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  final _appRouter = AppRouter();

  AppWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    ref.listen<AsyncValue<AuthState>>(initializationProvider, (previous, next) {
      next.whenData((state) {
        state.maybeMap(
          orElse: () {},
          authenticated: (_) => appRouter.pushAndPopUntil(
            const StarredRoute(),
            predicate: (route) => false,
          ),
          unAuthenticated: () => _appRouter.pushAndPopUntil(
            const SignInRoute(),
            predicate: (route) => false,
          ),
        );
      });
    });
  }
}
```

When the `Authstate` changes, I want to recall the `ref.read` and rebuild the widgets.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use the `ref.watch` method to keep your provider updated correctly with new dependencies:

```
final initializationProvider = FutureProvider<AuthState>((ref) async {
  ref.watch(authNotifierProvider);

  final authNotifier = ref.watch(authNotifierProvider.notifier);
  final state = await authNotifier.checkAndUpdateAuthStatus();
  return state;
});
```

Comment: Generally, there's no need to ref.watch a notifier.  Despite its name, it doesn't notify anything. :)